# Capitalize! Hackerrank problem in Strings section

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to solve this problem where you have to capitalize the first and last name entered as input. Following is my code:

```
def solve(s):


    list1=list(s)
    l1str="".join(list1)
    l1=l1str.split(' ')[0]
    newlist=list(l1)
    newlist[0]=newlist[0].upper()
    partone="".join(newlist)


    l2=l1str.split(' ')[1]
    newlist2= list(l2)
    newlist2[0]=newlist2[0].upper()
    parttwo="".join(newlist2)


    return(partone +" "+ parttwo)
```

The part which is already provided:

```
__name__ == '__main__':
fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')

s = input()

result = solve(s)

fptr.write(result + '\n')

fptr.close()
```

It does work for any custom case that I enter, and the first test case of Hackerrank as well which was 'hello world' but it fails all the other test cases and says that it is because of runtime error. What can I fix?

Comment: Suggested failing testcase: `amenhotep`.

Comment: Your indentation is clearly wrong; please [edit] to fix it. On the desktop version of this site, you can get code marked up for you by pasting your code, selecting the pasted block, and typing ctrl-K.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
def solve(s):
    return " ".join([name.capitalize() for name in s.split(" ")])
```

explanation

```
#s.split(" ") and capitalize() then join them using join()
```

Another detailed approach:

```
def solve(s):
    answer =""
    l = s.split(" ")
    for i in l:
        if i.isdigit():
            answer += i +" "
        else:
            answer+= i.capitalize()+" "
    return answer.strip()
```

Comment: Thanks! I think the error was coming from not detecting the second part of the string (if we only entered the first name and not the last name as input) as the list index was out of range.

Comment: can you also explain why did you use s.split(" ") in place of just s.split() and also .strip() at the end

Comment: `s.split(" ") ` and `s.split()` is the same thing by default. `strip()`  is used to remove any blank spaces.